# Control XML Output with tick boxws

Tags: php, xml, content-management-system

I made an XML file using a PHP script that creates nodes and populates them by looping through an array generated from a query. Now I am interested in making a backend PHP section where users can select tick boxes to specify which nodes they want in the XML file.

This is so the XML file can be tailored to their specific needs. In theory i would like the tick box to be able to change what is looped through or simply remove a node from the XML file.

In its simplest theoretical form...

```
if(tickbox == checked){
output xml node by looping or just display specified node
} else{
dont... as we dont want this one
}
```

Here is the PHP Script

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');

mysql_connect('mysql17.000webhost.com','user','pass');
mysql_select_db('a8273293_blogger');

$sql = "Select * from Messages";
$q = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$data = $dom->createElement('data');
$dom->appendChild($data);

while($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
  $text = $dom->createElement('text');
$textContent = $dom->createTextNode($r['text']);
$text->appendChild($textContent);

  $posted_at = $dom->createElement('posted_at');
$posted_atContent = $dom->createTextNode($r['posted_at']);
$posted_at->appendChild($posted_atContent);

  $messages = $dom->createElement('messages');
$messages->appendChild($text);
$messages->appendChild($posted_at);

  $data->appendChild($messages);
}

$xmlString = $dom->saveXML();
echo $xmlString;

?>
```

Could I make it so that when a box is ticked, a node is removed or hidden?

The theory

- a form with tick boxes
- each tickbox has a name
- these are used in my php script above
- if statements control output

Comment: what is your question about?

Comment: Sorry, I will make it more precise.

Comment: the context is clear, but what about the codes that does this

Comment: Oh I see, its a PHP script, i will post an example

Comment: here's a start: of course you would need a form, then from there, you'd set conditions, you should compare the user inputs, if its checked then add, if not then don't include. its a bit broad

Comment: So i could create a form and link it to my PHP script? I see, I shall edit my question to include more detail.

Comment: First don't use `mysql_*` functions. Second - I hope it's not real logins to your database.

Comment: @JesseOrange what would the checkbox contain anyway? the column names?

Comment: You're all correct in your theories. Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do first is of course, you have to setup a form. You must first predefine a column array which will hold all of your column names to be used in your form.

```
// pre defined columns
$columns = array('text' => 'Text', 'posted_at' => 'Posted At', 'messages' => 'Messages');
```

This will be also used in looping the form and filtering results as well.

Then you should create the from based on the array defined:

```
<form method="POST">
    <?php foreach($columns as $column => $label): ?>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="<?php echo $column; ?>" />
            <?php echo $label; ?>
        </label><br/>
    <?php endforeach; ?><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate" />
</form>
```

After the form has been setup, you would process which checkboxes has been selected. Of course the main idea is, process those inputs which has been checked only.

To filter the submitted items, intersect them with the default values. In turn, you would have the ones that have been selected:

```
// filtered array
$selection = array_intersect($_POST['selection'], $columns);
```

After that, the process of creating the nodes should just be a simple loop with an if condition in it using `in_array()`. In the end, this would be the idea:

```
<?php

// pre defined columns
$columns = array('text' => 'Text', 'posted_at' => 'Posted At', 'messages' => 'Messages');

if(isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['selection'])) { // if submitted

    // filtered array
    $selection = array_intersect($_POST['selection'], $columns);
    // connection using mysqli, select query blah blah
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM messages';
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    // initialize domdocument and set the parent node
    $data = $dom->createElement('data');
    $dom->appendChild($data);

    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        // loop the rows, create a node for each row
        $node = $textContent = null;
        $row = $dom->createElement('row');

        foreach($r as $column_name => $val) {
            // so loop all the values on each row

            if(in_array($column_name, $selection)) {
                // so foreach column, check if its selected by the user
                // if yes, its inside the selected array, create the node
                $node = $dom->createElement($column_name);
                $textContent = $dom->createTextNode($val);
                $node->appendChild($textContent);

            }
            // then append it inside the row node
            $row->appendChild($node);

        }
        // append the whole row inside the parent
        $data->appendChild($row);
    }

    header('Content-type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"');
    $xmlString = $dom->saveXML();
    echo $xmlString;
    exit;
}

?>

<form method="POST">
    <?php foreach($columns as $column => $label): ?>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="<?php echo $column; ?>" />
            <?php echo $label; ?>
        </label><br/>
    <?php endforeach; ?><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate" />
</form>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66529/discussion-on-answer-by-ghost-control-xml-output-with-tick-boxws).